# Wait for response from api using http.post in Angular 4

Tags: angular, for-loop, asynchronous, response

So I am trying to create packages in rapid succession with a for loop. I try to do this with a for loop and a api call, this api call makes the package. My loop has to wait for the return of each call but it doesn't.

I also dont like to change my backend.service to a Promise instead of a Observable. Is it possible to do this with a Observable?

**component.ts**

```
for (let i = 0; i < this.dataArray.length; i++) {
  this.backend.createPackage(this.package, this.hasPackagePhoto, this.wantsPackageLabel).subscribe(data => {
    let d = data as any;
    this.backend.packageTrackTrace = d.package.tracktrace;
    this.backend.awsLink = d.label;
  }, error => {
    this.backend.showMessage(false, 'Foutcode 2a: Het toevoegen van een pakket is niet gelukt.');
    console.log(error);
    this.errorMsg = "Verkeerde postcode!";
  }
  );
}
```

**backend.service.ts**

```
createPackage(p: Package, photo: Boolean, label: Boolean): Observable<Response> {
    const h = new Headers({ 'Content-Type': 'application/json', 'x-access-token': this.auth.getToken() });
    const options = new RequestOptions({ headers: h });

    const pt: any = {
        type: p.type,
        sender: p.sender,
        recipient: p.recipient,
        weight: p.weight,
        value: p.value,
        photo: photo,
        label: label,
        instructions: p.instructions
    };
    if (p.owner != null) {
        pt.owner = p.owner;
    }
    if (p.size != null) {
        pt.size = p.size;
    }

    return this.http.post(`${this.config.apiBase}/packages`, pt, options)
        .map((res:Response) => {
            this.newPackageCallbacks.forEach(cb => {
                cb();
            });
            return this.parseJSON(res);
        })
        .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd create a recursive function for it:

```
createPackages(count: number, i = 0) {
  if (i >= count) return;
  this.backend.createPackage(this.package, this.hasPackagePhoto, this.wantsPackageLabel).subscribe(data => {
    let d = data as any;
    this.backend.packageTrackTrace = d.package.tracktrace;
    this.backend.awsLink = d.label;
    this.createPackages(count, ++i);
  }, error => {
    this.backend.showMessage(false, 'Foutcode 2a: Het toevoegen van een pakket is niet gelukt.');
    console.log(error);
    this.errorMsg = "Verkeerde postcode!";
  });
}
```

and invoke: `this.createPackages(this.dataArray.length);`

Answer (score 0):

You can make your loop an observable and `concatMap()` to createPackage.

The callbacks might be a problem if they are slow. You might want to execute those in the outer subscribe.

```js
Observable.from(this.dataArray)
  .concatMap(() => 
    this.backend.createPackage(this.package, this.hasPackagePhoto, this.wantsPackageLabel);
  )
  .subscribe(
    data => {

      // Execute callbacks here if they need to complete before next package 
      this.backend.newPackageCallbacks.forEach(cb => {
        cb();
      });

      let d = data as any;
      this.backend.packageTrackTrace = d.package.tracktrace;
      this.backend.awsLink = d.label;
    }, 
    error => {
      this.backend.showMessage(false, 'Foutcode 2a: Het toevoegen van een pakket is niet gelukt.');
      console.log(error);
      this.errorMsg = "Verkeerde postcode!";
    }
   )
```

To illustrate `concatMap()` vs `flatMap()`, here's some dummy code

```js
console.clear() 
const Observable = Rx.Observable;

// Dummy setup for testing
let counter = 0;
const backendService = {
  createThePackage: () => {
    return Observable.of('y' + counter++)
      .delay((6 - counter) * 10) // delay to resolve in order of 3, 2, 1
  }
}
const dataArray = [1,2,3]


// flatMap takes order of resolving
counter = 0;
Observable.from(dataArray)
  .flatMap(() => { 
    return backendService.createThePackage();
  })
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log('flatMap: ' + x)
  })

// concatMap takes order of creating
counter = 0;
Observable.from(dataArray)
  .concatMap(() => { 
    return backendService.createThePackage();
  })
  .subscribe(x => {
    console.log('concatMap: ' + x)
  })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/rxjs/5.5.2/Rx.js"></script>
```